# Matrix Multiply method in C#

Tags: c#, matrix

I dont really understand the method Matrix.Multiply(Matrix m) in C#.

Let say I have 2 matrices. 1 matrix is in world space and 1 matrix in local space, now I want to transform world space to local space or from local space to world space, what should I do with the Multiply method?

```
Matrix world = ....

Matrix local = ...

world.Multiply(local) 
// It means world*local or local*world and it will transform world space to 
// local or from local to world space?
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to multiply the matrixes if you want to transform one matrix into the other. You want to find the matrix you need to multiply one *by* to go from one to the other. Essentially, you want to solve the equation:

```
W * X = L
```

Where `W` is your world matrix and `L` is your local matrix. You're looking for matrix `X`. Solving for `X`:

```
W * X * 1/L = I
```

Where `I` is the identity matrix and `1/L` is the inverse of `L`  So:

```
X = 1/W * L
```

Note that matrix multiplication is *not* commutative, so `W * L` is not the same, in general, as `L * W`.

Comment: +1 Especially for pointing out that matrix multiplication is not commutative